# Shall I use MongoDB or CouchDB or anything else?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, couchdb, redis

I'm developing a monitoring system using node.js + Redis to read the HTTP response from a web page and decide if it's up or down. However, I'm doing this every minute and I need to store the results to show to the end user.

How and which database should I use to save the data and present it in almost real-time? Even if I have few urls beings monitored, given that I get a response once every minute, there will be tons of data to show.

Thanks

Comment: My vote also goes out to redis. node_redis is insanely fast :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the fastest solution will be Redis which also offers very useful commands for storing statistical data. I [asked](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/948b237a25fab7c8) similar question on Redis google groups and it seemed to be a good use case for this DB.

Answer (score 3):

Redis.

You are already using it. It supports disk backing and replication. Go for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old article but still fairly valid as far as a good example of using MongoDB for real time analytics: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/171353301/using-mongodb-for-real-time-analytics